# animating differently colored points in mayavi

Tags: python, data-visualization, vtk, mayavi

I am trying to animate the evolution of vertex rings in a fluid. The data is just an array with x,y,z information for particles which then create the rings. To visualize them I use mayavi and just plotting the current position at each time step works fine. The problems come when trying to animate all positions into a "movie". For simply plotting I use mlab.point3D and cycle trough the array giving each ring its own color like in the example below:

```
N = 0
for i in range(0,N_rings):
    fig = mlab.points3d(res_alpha[0,N:N + ring[i].N_p - 1,0,0], res_alpha[0,N:N + ring[i].N_p - 1,1,0], res_alpha[0,N:N + ring[i].N_p - 1,2,0], scale_factor=0.1, color = ring[i].color)
    N = N + ring[i].N_p
```

How do I do the same in the animation-function?
I tried to use fig.mlab_source.set but I it doesn't work. I think it wants to have all information at once but how do I keep the colors then? Any suggestions?

---

Edit:
Too make it more clear here is a working example of what I mean

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

pointsx = [5,5,5]
pointsy = [0,5,10]
z = np.linspace(0, 10, 3)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
xv, pointsz = np.meshgrid(z, y)
colors = [(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)]

N = 0

"""
N = 0
for i in range(0,3):
    mlab.points3d(pointsx[N], pointsy[N], pointsz[0], scale_factor=0.1, color = colors[i])
    N = N + 1"""

fig = mlab.points3d(pointsx, pointsy, pointsz[0], scale_factor=0.1, color = (1,0,0))
mlab.axes(extent=[0,10,0,10,0,10])

@mlab.animate(delay=1000, ui=True)
def anim():
    for i in range(0,100):
        fig.mlab_source.set(x=pointsx, y=pointsy, z=pointsz[i])
        yield

anim()
mlab.show()
```

It animates three points moving in one direction. How can I make them have different colors? The commented out block of code is what I use to make single plots to have them different colors, but it doesn't work in the animation.

Comment: There's several examples [here](https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html#animating-a-visualization) .Posting a minimum working example would help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added a working example. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the loop you commented out is what you want to animate. If so, that loop does not run (`pointsx[N]` is not an array)

Comment: The commented out part is like printing one frame of the "animation" below where every point has its own color. I know that points[N] is not an array but for the animation it is irrelevant how many points there are. 
I reword my question: How can I animate points in mlab and have independent control of their colors?

Comment: I understand what you're implying with the commented code. I tried to run it to get a better grip of the behaviour you're looking for. The thing is that it doesn't run because the x,y and z parameters of `points3d` do not have the same (array) shape. Do mind that you're *always* using `pointsz[…]` *and* using `pointsx[…]` and `pointsx` alternately in *both* `anim` and the code that's commented out.

Comment: It works when I run it and does what it is supposed to do. Can your error stem from different versions of mayavi/VTK/wxpython?